# I am facing issue with docker and my remote database. My application works fine when i am not creating nginx vhost for docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, networking

New to Docker containers (Thanks in advance)
I am running docker container in my machine, it seems working fine but it is not connecting to my database machine (trying to login it fails). Bridge network i am using here.

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255

docker ip address is 172.17.0.2 and database machine ip is 172.16.20.xx
How can i connect my docker application with mysql which is not running in docker but on centos machine, is possible to do it ? nginx i am using here for multiple container proxy !

command for docker run :

docker run -d -p 8083:80 --name=container-name containerV:1.0

8083 is proxy to nginx 80 port and application is accessed by FQDN.
I can ping database machine from docker container !
Strange thing Note: when i turn nginx off and application is accessed from ip_address:8083 and then when i try to login it works fine !
I am very confused and can find any help here to solve this issue !
Application details: php laravel simple application

update:

DB machine is in the same network of docker host machine, docker container is connecting to DB but logins fails and says invalid credentials and page goes to apache not found url not found.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:8.10.0 AS node
FROM php:7.3-apache


COPY --from=node /usr/local/lib/node_modules /usr/local   /lib/node_modules
COPY --from=node /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node
RUN ln -s /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js /usr/local/bin/npm


RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y nano wget libwebp-dev   libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng-dev libxpm-dev \
libfreetype6-dev net-tools
RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y \
    zlib1g-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install mbstring

RUN apt-get install -y libzip-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip

RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-dev  libxml2-dev autoconf g++ imagemagick libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-    dev li>
docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    --with-gd \
    --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ \
    --with-png-dir=/usr/include/ \
    --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ && \
pecl install imagick && \
docker-php-ext-enable imagick

RUN apt-get install -y git openssh-client zip unzip gconf-service     libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 \
                   libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 \
                   libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 \
                   libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 \
                   ca-certificates fonts-liberation  libnss3 lsb-  release xdg-utils wget

RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY ./App-dir /var/www/html
RUN chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html -R
RUN chmod 777 -R storage/ bootstrap/ public/
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2enmod ssl  
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/local /bin/composer
RUN composer install
RUN php artisan key:generate --force
RUN composer update
RUN composer dump-autoload
RUN npm install
RUN npm run prod
```

Nginx config file website.conf

```
server {
# Setup the domain name(s)
server_name website.com;
listen 80;
#return 301 https://website.com$request_uri;
# If you would like to gzip your stuff
gzip on;
gzip_min_length 1;
gzip_types *;

# Setup the proxy
# This will forward all requests to the server
# and then it will relay the servers response back to the client

add_header 'Content-Security-Policy' 'upgrade-insecure-requests';
charset utf-8;
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8083;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_buffering off;
proxy_request_buffering off;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_intercept_errors on;


 }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a [mcve]?  The various low-level networking diagnostics are probably less interesting than knowing what's inside the `containerV:1.0` image, what address you're trying to connect to, and what the exact error you're getting is.

Comment: images of Dockerfile and nginx .conf file attached. Let me tell you one thing when i try to access application without nginx it works fine, but when i am using nginx proxy for domain name and access it  then it will access the site but login to site fails with invalid credentials and give me error Not found the request url not found

Comment: You seem to have edited in three links to PNG files.  Those aren't runnable and they're hard to read and search for later.  Please include the actual source code (not images) in the question itself (not behind links).

Comment: @DavidMaze Dockerfile and nginx conf file uploaded in markup !

Comment: @DavidMaze this was totally browser issue, it works fine on chrome but it still not working firefox ! All the configuration are working fine, I am happy that my configuration are working fine :-)